# PERL : Using Text::Wrap and specify the end of line

Tags: perl, word-wrap

Yes, I'm re-writing cowsay :)

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use Text::Wrap;
$Text::Wrap::columns = 40;

my $FORTUNE = "The very long sentence that will be outputted by another command and it can be very long so it is word-wrapped The very long sentence that will be outputted by another command and it can be very long so it is word-wrapped";

my $TOP = " _______________________________________
/                                       \\
";
my $BOTTOM = "\\_______________________________________/
";

print $TOP;
print wrap('| ', '| ', $FORTUNE) . "\n";
print $BOTTOM;
```

Produces this

```
 _______________________________________
/                                       \
| The very long sentence that will be
| outputted by another command and it
| can be very long so it is
| word-wrapped The very long sentence
| that will be outputted by another
| command and it can be very long so it
| is word-wrapped
\_______________________________________/
```

How can I get this ?

```
 _______________________________________
/                                       \
| The very long sentence that will be   |
| outputted by another command and it   |
| can be very long so it is             |
| word-wrapped The very long sentence   |
| that will be outputted by another     |
| command and it can be very long so it |
| is word-wrapped                       |
\_______________________________________/
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could not find a way in the documentation, but you can apply a small hack if you save the string. It is possible to assign a new line ending by using a package variable:

```
$Text::Wrap::separator = "|$/";
```

You also need to prevent the module from expanding tabs and messing with the character count:

```
$Text::Wrap::unexpand = 0;
```

This is simply a pipe `|` followed by the input record separator `$/` (newline most often). This will add a pipe to the end of the line, but no padding space, which will have to be added manually:

```
my $text = wrap('| ', '| ', $FORTUNE) . "\n";
$text =~ s/(^.+)\K\|/' ' x ($Text::Wrap::columns - length($1)) . '|'/gem;
print $text;
```

This will match the beginning of each line, ending with a `|`, add the padding space by multiplying a space by columns minus length of matched string. We use the `/m` modifier to make `^` match newlines inside the string. `.+` by itself will not match newlines, which means each match will be an entire line. The `/e` modifier will "eval" the replacement part as code, not a string.

Note that it is somewhat of a quick hack, so bugs are possible.

Comment: Thanks TLP ; I cannot get this to work (I get the same results w/o the expected trailing pipe), probably because I fail to understand where that $1 comes from?

Comment: Oh, right, I forgot one part... I'll add that. And no, `$1` is the string captured by the parentheses `(^.+)`.

Comment: Great :) Almost there. It works, but the `|` ending the lines that start with spaces (indented) is off by the number of spaces. Thank you very much for your help, TLP.

Comment: It seems the module inserts tabs automagically when you have enough spaces. And a tab counts differently when it comes to `length`. Perhaps there is a way to override that.

Comment: It seems the `unexpand` variable fixes that. Unfortunately, it also removes existing tabs, but you can't have everything.

Answer (score 2):

If you're willing to download a more powerful module, you can use [Text::Format](http://search.cpan.org/~shlomif/Text-Format-0.59/lib/Text/Format.pm). It has a lot more options for customizing, but the most relevant one is `rightFill` which fills the rest of the columns in each line with spaces.

Unfortunately, you can't customize the left and right sides with non-space characters. You can use a workaround by doing regex substitutions, just as [Text::NWrap](http://search.cpan.org/~gabor/Text-Format0.52+NWrap0.11/lib/Text/NWrap.pm) does in its source code.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use utf8;
use Text::Format;

chop(my $FORTUNE = "The very long sentence that will be outputted by another command and it can be very long so it is word-wrapped " x 2);

my $TOP =  "/" . '‾'x39 . "\\\n";
my $BOTTOM = "\\_______________________________________/\n";

my $formatter = Text::Format->new({ columns => 37, firstIndent => 0, rightFill => 1 });
my $text = $formatter->format($FORTUNE);
$text =~ s/^/| /mg;
$text =~ s/\n/ |\n/mg;

print $TOP;
print $text;
print $BOTTOM;
```